# spring.jackson.date-format add extra 4 hours to given input

Tags: datetime, spring-boot, oracle11g

I want to format `java.util.Date`.I get year month and day correctly but when I insert data to database I get 4 more hour.For example if I insert 2017-12-18 12:00
then inserted row will be 2017-12-18 16:00

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String insertRequest(@RequestBody EmployeeRequest employeeRequest) {
    System.out.println(employeeRequest.getDate());
    requestService.insertRequest(employeeRequest);   
    return "inserted and sent mail";
}
```

My model :

```
 @NotNull
private Date date;
```

My `application.properties`

```
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a date formatting error, this is very likely related to TimeZone. Depending on how your Database and Application Server are configured it appears that they are using different default timezone's.

Have you tried reading the data back OUT of the database into Java? If the database is properly storing the timezone then it should Just Work when you read it back into your java object. If not, i'd suggest first updating your Date/Time format to include the timezone e.g. `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ`. Then the database should at least have access to the appropriate timezone.

If this doens't work, the proper mitigation really depends on your application and how it needs to make use of time / timezones. It could be that what you have is actually fine, it's just that when you manually inspect the database it's displaying to you the time in the default timezone. You could also just set your database and app servers to use the same timezone, but this can be a configuration nightmare.

Side note: as some general advice, I'd high recommend using either `java.time.*` or `jodatime` libraries instead of `java.util.Date` if at all possible. This isn't related to this specific issue, but they are much more robust date/time libraries than the legacy `java.util.Date`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I check database , there is everything normal.When I insert data ,it just show only 4 more hours

Comment: Then it's most definitely a timezone issue. How to solve it really depends on your application needs. Generally I'd suggest storing all dates to the database as UTC and reading them out using `java.time.LocalDateTime` so that no timezone changes occur during the data storage. Then you can manually update the timezone as needed.

Comment: I set 'application.properties'  'spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC' but still give me same extra hour.Can you give me hint where else can be wrong ?

Comment: Thank you so much. You gave me right path to follow.I solved the problem following this (https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/) can help someone who face the same problem.